# Get list of wordpress Post ID's based on category ID in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a large wp install with 400k+ custom posts.
I want to clean it up and remove a lot of posts.

I want to remove ALL posts in certain categories, i have a category with e.g ID 1234 which holds 50k posts.

So i am trying to follow this tutorial https://laloah.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/how-to-delete-thousands-of-posts-in-wordpress-via-phpmyadmin/

In order to do that i need to select all IDs of posts in a category, so i am using this code to select all IDs and insert them into a table

```
insert into poststodelete 
SELECT DISTINCT post_id  
           FROM wp_postmeta 
          WHERE meta_value Like "1234";
```

I follow the rest of the tutorial and it should delete all posts. However on the front end i still see posts in category 1234.

Then i go back to phpmyadmin to see if there are still posts with that category ID

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id 
           FROM wp_postmeta 
          WHERE meta_value Like "1234";
```

But now it returns 0 values, so all posts in the category should have been deleted, no? What am i missing here?

The rest of the code i used to delete the post comes from the tutorial

```
(select a.id from wp_posts a inner join poststodelete b on a.post_parent=b.id);

DELETE a, b
FROM wp_commentmeta a
inner join wp_comments b on a.comment_id=b.comment_id
inner join poststodelete c on b.comment_post_ID=c.id;

DELETE a FROM wp_term_relationships a inner join poststodelete b on a.object_id=b.id;

DELETE a FROM wp_postmeta a inner join poststodelete b on a.post_id=b.id;

DELETE a FROM wp_posts a inner join poststodelete b on a.id=b.id;

update wp_term_taxonomy t set count=(select count(*) from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id=t.term_taxonomy_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are filling poststodelete searching into wp_postsmeta but actually WP stores post <-> category relation inside [_wp_term_relationships](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_term_relationships) therefore your initial query isn't taking the right posts i guess. Object_id are your post IDs while term_tax_id is the ID of wp_term_taxonomy which store your category id related to it's taxonomy

Comment: Thanks, so if i understand i can also not query wp_term_relationships as it holds the taxonomy ID but not the value.

I will need to find a way to get all post IDs for posts in the category ID "1234"

Comment: If you know that "1234" is your TERM id then you just need to search it into wp_term_taxonomy, get the ID of that table, join it with term_relationship and go on deleting ^^